# Nginx redirects - query string

Tags: nginx

I have some URLs that I'm looking at creating redirects for. They are in the following format:

```
/testing?returnUrl=/homepage
/another?returnUrl=/contact
```

I'm trying to redirect them with the following

```
rewrite ^/testing$ / permanent;
```

This isn;t working, so I'm guessing the syntax is incorrect

I'm not sure how to deal woth the `?` and `=`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nginx variables for query string values take the format `$arg_name`, so here you would use `$arg_returnUrl`